# Angular Regexp Directive

Tags: regex, angular, directive

I'm trying to create an Angular Directive in Angular 7 to pass in a RegExp via an input property and don't allow the user to type characters that don't match the RegExp.

It's working to a degree, but the RegExp I'm trying to validate seems to be failing on the . character.

in my HTML

```
    <input type="text" alphaNumeric="^(\d{1,3}|\d{0,3}\.\d{1,2})$">>
```

In my Directive

```
  @Input('alphaNumeric') pattern: string;

  // Listen for the input event to also handle copy and paste.
  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target.value'])
  onInput(value: string) {

    if (this.pattern && this.pattern !== '' ) { 

     let patternRegExp : RegExp = new RegExp(this.pattern, 'g');

     if (!patternRegExp.test(value)) {
          this.el.control.patchValue(value.slice(0, -1));  
     }
 }
```

The RegExp is supposed to be allowing up to 3 digits or up to 3 digits and 2 decimal places, i.e. allow 345 or 343.45. The RexExp works on it's own on a RegExp tester.

What I'm seeing is that it's preventing typing letters, but also preventing typing the . character, so you can type 333 but can't type 33.45.

I was reading that RegExp can be \ escaped or the whole RegExp wrapped in / characters, have tried various things but can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you please share the regex

Comment: Also a [mcve] if possible

Comment: RegExp added, I'll try to create a stackBlitz for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change regex to `^(\d{1,3}|\d{0,3}\.\d{0,2})$` (just 1 is replaced by 0 in the end). in your case when somebody types `.` it does not match the regex `\.\d{1,2}` yet (because at least one digit is required by the regex), and as a result the dot got erased.

Comment: could you please mark question as answered, so people would see the problem is resolved in the list of questions